# Do t-test on R from a frequency table

Tags: r

Suppose I have a frequency table with several hundreds rows.

```
Group Score Frequency  
    A     0     12687      
    B     0      9965
    A     1      4567
    B     1      3520
    A     2       963
    B     2      1024
    A     3       985
    B     3      1124    

Continue with more rows
```

How do I calculate the mean, standard error of score for each group and do a t test comparing the mean score of two groups in R?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute mean of each group:

```
require(data.table)

df <- fread("Group Score Frequency  
A     0     12687      
B     0      9965
A     1      4567
B     1      3520
A     2       963
B     2      1024
A     3       985
B     3      1124")

df[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=Group]
```

Which results into:

```
   Group Score Frequency
1:     A   1.5   4800.50
2:     B   1.5   3908.25
```

Comment: Oops I think I didn't ask the question well. I'll try to explain in this way: There's 12687 people in group A got 0 point, 4567 people in group A got 1 point and etc.. So how's the overall average score in each group? How's the variance? Since I only have this kind of frequency table rather than million rows of row data, is it possible to do t test directly through this table to compare the mean score between the groups?

Comment: @Chih-TaoYeh Actually I am not sure but it might not be possible.